# Email confirmation With php

Tags: php, email, registration

MY problem is not the email successfully sending, it is the confirmation page on my website. The email has already sent to the user, but when they click the link to activate their password it then brings them to a confirmation page, and it supposed to confirm the activation, and register them, but it is not doing anything at all. IT just shows up a blank page, and i even checked the databases, and nothing is changed. I would like any help, and i also have the code below for it. Any help would be great.

```
<?php

include('sqlconfig.php');

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB"); 

/* Confirmation Code */
$passkey=$_GET['passkey'];
$tbl_name1="temp_users";

/*retrieve data */
$sql1="SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE confirm='$passkey'";
$result1=mysql_query($sql1);

if($result1){
$count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

/*Fetch The data From the table */
if($count==1){
$rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
$Email=$rows['email'];
$First_Name=$rows['FirstN'];
$Last_name=$rows['LastN'];
$password=$rows['password']; 
$phone=$rows['phone'];
$tbl_name2="users";

/*Insert data into new users table */
$sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, phone)VALUES('$First_Name', '$Last_name', '$Email', '$password', '$phone')";
$result2=mysql_query($sql2);
}

/*If passkey is not found*/
else {
echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
}

/*If activation successful, show, and delete old data from temp table*/
if($result2){

echo "Your account has been activated";

// Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey 
$sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
$result3=mysql_query($sql3);

}


}
?>
```

Comment: You are **wide open** to SQL injection attacks, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: A blank page doesn't say much; add `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(-1);` at the top of your script and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

if($passkey == NULL) //check for passkey whether it is null or not, this might be the reason of blank screen

{
echo "invalid action on page"; // some error message
}

else
 {
$flag = FALSE; // initiate somewhere at the begining of script

```
    /*retrieve data */
    $sql1="SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE confirm='$passkey'";

    $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

    if(mysql_num_rows($result1))
        {
        $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
        $Email=$rows['email'];
        $First_Name=$rows['FirstN'];
        $Last_name=$rows['LastN'];
        $password=$rows['password']; 
        $phone=$rows['phone'];
        $tbl_name2="users";

        /*Insert data into new users table */
        $sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, phone)VALUES('$First_Name', '$Last_name', '$Email', '$password', '$phone')";
        if(mysql_query($sql2))
            {
            $flag = TRUE;
            }

        }
    /*If passkey is not found*/
    else 
        {
        echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
        }

    /*If activation successful, show, and delete old data from temp table*/
    if($flag)
        {
        echo "Your account has been activated";
        // Delete information of this user from table "temp_members_db" that has this passkey 
        $sql3="DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = '$passkey'";
        $result3=mysql_query($sql3);
        }
```

}

first the code will check whether there is any result coming from the query, if yes then it fetches data and insert into the table2.

a new variable flag is introduced to check whether query2 is executed, if so then query 3 is executed.

Edit : first check whether the passkey coming contains some value or not, if no it shows error, else rest of code execute

Comment: -1, this is a copy and paste of the original code.  You have not explained what you changed, why you changed it, and how the changes help.

Comment: @Charles  i have changed the code and as you wanted a description, i have added that description too

Comment: Thank you very much, i will try the code out and see, and as for the MySQL injection stuff i didn't include any in the old script because this is only run on my computer, and i only have access to it. Once i upload it to the real server, i will be sure to protect it.

Comment: Didnt work, i tried it, brought up a blank page. I modified it a little, and it still brought up a blank page either way.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested and it certainly needs some modification but:

```
<?php

include('sqlconfig.php');

//Connect to Database
$mysqli = new mysqli($hostname, $username, $password, $databasename);
//PHP > 5.3.0
if ($mysqli->connect_error) {
    die('Connect Error (' . $mysqli->connect_errno . ') '
            . $mysqli->connect_error);
}

/* Confirmation Code */
$passkey = $_GET['passkey'];
$tbl_name1 = "temp_users";


/* create a prepared statement */
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM temp_users WHERE confirm=?")) {

    $stmt->bind_param("s", $passkey);
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    $rows = $result->fetch_assoc();

    $stmt->close();

    $Email = $rows['email'];
    $First_Name = $rows['FirstN'];
    $Last_name = $rows['LastN'];
    $password = $rows['password'];
    $phone = $rows['phone'];
    $tbl_name2 = "users";

    /* Create table doesn't return a resultset */
    if ($mysqli->query("INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(First Name, Last Name, Email, Password, phone)VALUES('$First_Name', '$Last_name', '$Email', '$password', '$phone')") === TRUE) {
        echo "Your account has been activated";

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("DELETE FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE confirm_code = ?")) {
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $passkey);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->close();
        }
    }
    else {
        echo "Wrong Confirmation code";
    }
}
```

Note: when using the value of `$_GET['passkey']` in a select query, we use `bind_param`to avoid SQL injection.

And I **strongly** recommend the reading of this: http://php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated

Comment: You have failed to explain what you changed, why you changed it, and how the changes help.  The conversion to mysqli spared you a downvote, but still, c'mon.

Comment: I have changed everything because given the information we have, it is hard to know where the error is...